# Django Rest Framework serializers beautiful output

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have model of category and need to serialize to give beautiful output.

My model

```
class Categorie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

My serializer

```
class CategorieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Categorie
        fields = ['name']
```

My code

```
class JokesCategories(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        categories = Categorie.objects.all()
        serializer = CategorieSerializer(categories, many=True)
        output_data = {}
        for num, dictionary in enumerate(serializer.data):
            output_data[num] = dict(dictionary)['name']
        return Response(output_data)
```

I have output

```
{
    "0": "animal",
    "1": "career"
}
```

But need

```
[
    0: "animal",
    1: "career"
]
```

Help for you advices.

Comment: The latter is not valid JSON, hence that is not possible: the keys of a JSON object are always strings. See https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Answer (score 0):

**You can't**. A JSON object always has *strings* as keys, not integers. This is part of the [*JSON specifications* <sup>[json.org]</sup>](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). You can for example use [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/) to check if a certain text is valid JSON, and the latter is not.

Python's JSON encoder thus will fallback on converting the integers into strings to produce a valid JSON blob. Your dictionary indeed produced integers as keys, but the serializer thus converts it to strings.

Here it however might make more sense to use a *list*, and not an object, since the keys (indices) start at `0` and are incremental. Using a dictionary/JSON object thus does not make much sense:

```
class JokesCategories(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        categories = Categorie.objects.all()
        serializer = CategorieSerializer(categories, many=True)
        output_data = [data['name'] for item in serializer.data]
        return Response(output_data)
```